# Проблема с адаптивной версткой сайта

Tags: html, css

Не получается реализовать адаптив под телефон

Телефонная версия включается если выбрать в хроме (Версия для ПК)

https://romariofreelancer.github.io/site/

https://github.com/RomarioFreeLancer/site

Comment: В чем у Вас конкретно проблема? Что не получается? Используйте медиа запросы css и всё получится.

Answer (score 0):

Можно по брейкпоинтам через css уменьшить как размеры блоков, там и шрифтов, где-то поменять внутреннюю структуру блоков.